# loading a ResourceDictionary from an XAML also loads files into memory

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, xamlreader

I have an XAML file that I load it as a ResourceDictionary using

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    // Read in ResourceDictionary File
                    ResourceDictionary dic =
                       (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(fs);

                    // Clear any previous dictionaries loaded
                    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
                    // Add in newly loaded Resource Dictionary
                    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dic);
                    fs.Close();
                }
```

inside that XAML, I have an ImageBrush. When I read the dictionary,MyApplication.vshost.exe is now using the image file that forms the ImageBrush. i.e. the file that in the Source property of the ImageBrush. I need to delete that file but it gives an error because the file is in use by another process. My question is how to do this properly so that the file is free to be deleted later.

Comment: Just a note: it's not necessary to call `fs.Close()` because the stream is automatically disposed of when exiting the using block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set [`BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx) on a `BitmapImage` in your `ImageBrush` resource by writing it like this:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="myImageBrush">
    <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="..." CacheOption="OnLoad"/>
    </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
</ImageBrush>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, that seems to be the source of the problem. When I edited the XAML manually to add above code of CacheOption it worked with no problem. However, ,manual editing is not an option and automatic editing will requires that I load the XAML first, but then if I load it first this will generate the very same error.

Comment: I managed to load it as XDocument instead. I modified it to be as above and then I load it again as ResourceDictionary this time. worked great